# Python flask form to create groupmessage, Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have the following group form

```
class GroupForm(FlaskForm):
    groepsnaam = StringField('groepsnaam', validators=[DataRequired()])
    deelnemer1 = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    deelnemer2 = StringField('Username2', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

This form is supposed to create a group with two users. I am implementing these groups using a certain message within my groupmessage model shown below

```
class Groupmessage(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.now)
    verstuurder = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    group = db.Column(db.String(140), db.ForeignKey('group.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Groupmessage {}>'.format(self.body)
```

I have combined these two using the following route

```
@app.route('/groups', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def GroupsPage():
    form = GroupForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        Groupmsg1 = Groupmessage(verstuurder=current_user, group=form.groepsnaam.data,
                      body="Ik ben de groep binnengetreden")
        Groupmsg2 = Groupmessage(verstuurder=form.deelnemer1.data, group=form.groepsnaam.data,
                      body="Ik ben de groep binnengetreden")
        Groupmsg3 = Groupmessage(verstuurder=form.deelnemer2.data, group=form.groepsnaam.data,
                      body="Ik ben de groep binnengetreden")
        db.session.add(Groupmsg1)
        db.session.add(Groupmsg2)
        db.session.add(Groupmsg3)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('The group is created!')
    return render_template('groups.html', form=form)
```

Upon submitting the form I get a wall of errors the most significant being

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

To be frank I do not know why paramater 2 is of an unsupported type, this is referring to the static setting of the body but I can't seem to find a way to fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem was the type of input for verstuurder not matching the id it is supposed to be